# Setting value in a class from enum in interfaces

Tags: java, class, enums, interface

I come across a difficulty in school assignment in creating a blackjack game.
We are required to apply score value in a class from a face value in an interface. I figure out the way is to modify enum directly by writing Ace(1),Two(2)... but we are not allowed modify the interface. Is there any other way I can apply the value?

```
public interface PlayingCard

public enum Value
{
    Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King
};

public class PlayingCardImp implements PlayingCard {

    private Suit suit;
    private Value value;

    public PlayingCardImp (Value value, Suit suit)
      {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
      }

    @Override
    public int getScore() 
    {   
     @return the score value of this card (Ace=1, J, Q, K=10, All others int of face value)
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also use a Map as of `Map<Value, Integer>` to create a sort of relationship between the enum and the cards value. (even though it might not be the best approach)

Comment: One simple way would be to do a switch on the enum Value and defince your return cases there.

Comment: Next time please provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `Value.ordinal()` and you get the "postion" of the value in the Enumeration, what is the value in your case.

EDIT to have the value 10 for Jack,Queen,and King use this:

```
 public int getScore() 
     if (value == Value.Ace)
       return 1;
     if (value == Value.Jack &&  value == Value.Queen && value == Value.King)
         return 10;

     return value.ordinal()+1;
```

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks i have overseen it. See my updated answer

Comment: @StefanWarminski or terny Operator. But especialy for beginneers the provided Solution is more understandable

Answer (score -1):

enums are simple constants. In case you are not allowed to modify the enum then You have to maintain associated value with additional data structure like some key-value pair.